# How do i get these results?

Tags: javascript

i am  a newbie to JavaScript.I am doing this

```
var obj = {
    a: "hello world",
    b: 42
};
var b = "a";

console.log(obj[b]);
console.log(obj["b"]);
```

The results are

```
    hello world  
42
```

But how come the `console.log(obj[b]);`shows  hello world?
I am confused.
please tell me. thanks,.

Comment: @Are you kidding the a is in "".

Comment: So dosen't it save string a?

Comment: `b` is `"a" `so `obj[b]` is `obj["a"]`.

Comment: `b = "a";` is value type  

for `obj[b]` JavaScript will evaluate like this `b` is a variable in brackets, so it returns
`obj["a"]` and it output the value `hello world`
for `console.log(obj["b"])`
directly  it will return 42

Answer (score 0):

You can access a value in the object by making use of it's key. In your object `obj`, it has 2 keys `a` and `b`, so to access `hello world`, you will use `obj["a"]`. In your case `b="a"`, so `"a"` can be replaced by variable `b`, therefore obj[b] will print `"hello world"`

Comment: so what if i have to put a string a inside variable b??

Comment: You have just put a string inside variable b, b="a" where "a" is a string, but you have used that string with the "obj[b]", so it will take it as its own key value "a". If you will do console.log(b) then you will get "a", a normal string.